# How read a file locked by another process in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, fs, file-locking

I want read the data inside a file that is locked by another process. Is there any native way or a package that would do that?

Trying a basic `fs.readFileSync` call will result in an `EBUSY` error.

Comment: File locking is for a reason.  Change the other process so the file is not locked for other readers and verify that that is actually safe.  Make a copy of the file before it is locked.  Also, what OS are you running on?

Comment: I need to create automatic backups from the files that are currently being used. Also I have no access to the source of the process that is locking the file.

Comment: Files are often locked against other readers because the files may be in an inconsistent state such as partially written or being updated (not appropriate for backup at that moment).  What most backup systems do is they keep retrying every once in awhile until the file is no longer locked.